# Finding the x-intercept of a cubic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, cubics

How would one go about solving for x in this cubic equation?

$f(x) = x^3 + x - 4$

I don't think factoring works in this situation:
$f(x) = x^2(x + 1) - 4$

and I don't know how to find the value of $x$ where f(x) = 0.

Comment: since there is just one real root, Cardano's method will work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula

Comment: @WillJagy that's the only method?

Comment: there is no magic wand. As it has complex roots, the cube roots in Cardano do not involve complex numbers, just real

Comment: The $x$-axis corresponds to the line $y=0$.  Factoring the function $f(x) = x(x^2 + 1) - 4$, in an of itself, doesn't seem to buy you anything.  All it (at least immediately) does is identify where $f(x)$ crosses the line $y = -4,$ which is **not** what you want.

Comment: the factorization has a typo. if u factor out $x^2$, then you should get $x^2(x+1/x)-4$. if you meant to factor out $x$ instead, then you get $x(x^2+1)-4$

Answer (score 1):

For solving cubic equations, Cardano's method is not the $\alpha$ and $\omega$.

If you follow the (simple) steps described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), you will immediately notice that there is only one real root since $\Delta=-436$.

So, use the [hyperbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root) and obtain
$$x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(6 \sqrt{3}\right)\right)$$ which is a bit nicer than
$$x=\frac{\sqrt[3]{18+\sqrt{327}}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3
   \left(18+\sqrt{327}\right)}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alright, define real numbers $u,v$  with, say, $u \geq v,$ then
$$ u^3 + v^3  = 4, $$
$$  3uv = -1$$
so that $$  u^3 v^3 = \frac{-1}{27}$$
This is enough information to solve for $u^3, v^3$ separately. Then $u,v$ separate. Meanwhile, the quantity $u+v$ is the real root of your original cubic.